# Change values in menu xml

Tags: java, android

In my android app I got main_activity.xml:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/head"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>
```

I would like to change `app:menu` value programatically, is there any way to do it?

Comment: What you want to change in menu ? please clarify in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *findViewById()* method to get a reference to the NavigationView object.

The NavigationView class provides a method *inflateMenu(resourceID)*.

Link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#inflateMenu%28int%29

Answer (score 1):

Crate a `NavigationView` object by `findViewById`

```
    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
```

You can change it at runtime by using below code...

```
    mNavigationView.getMenu().clear();
    mNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
```